# Creating Database in APACHE2 returning internal server error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, webserver, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to use my pi as a webserver. When I am attempting to create a Table in my database it is returning an internal server error. Can anyone try help me diagnose whats causing it?

```
    <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'anthony';
$dbname = "messages";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully<br />';
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message_tbl (
        message_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        message_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        message_subject VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        message_txt VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
        message_amount INT(10) NOT NULL, 
        message_die VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
        message_modifier INT(10) NOT NULL, 
        message_roll INT(10) NOT NULL
        )"; 
mysql_select_db( 'TUTORIALS' );
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Table created successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

I would usually atleast expect it to come back with Could not create table:. I have installed apache2, php, and mysql with a database called messages on my pi.

Comment: For starters, those database functions have been deprecated for five years and aren't even present in the latest version of PHP. I'd toss them out and start over again with PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's default port is 3306, not 3036. But you really should scrap that obsolete code and start fresh with PDO. Something like this might work. I'm on a device using the app so probably not my best work but should at least get you pointed in the right direction.

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=TUTORIALS", "root", "anthony");
    echo 'Connected successfully<br />';
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message_tbl (
        message_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        message_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        message_subject VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        message_txt VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
        message_amount INT(10) NOT NULL, 
        message_die VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
        message_modifier INT(10) NOT NULL, 
        message_roll INT(10) NOT NULL
    )";
    $conn->query($sql);
    echo "Table created successfully\n";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```